# A String is Required Here

Tags: crystal-reports

[Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnMmM.png) [Crystal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMumM.png)

I have a formula field that is giving me this error.

We migrated to new servers and the reports stopped working. I have updated the server info but now the formula fields are broken.

```
If IsDateTime(left({uvw_Comm_Talk_Log.COMM_DATETIME}, 10) + " " + mid({uvw_Comm_Talk_Log.COMM_DATETIME},12,8))
Then
CDateTime(left({uvw_Comm_Talk_Log.COMM_DATETIME}, 10) + " " + mid({uvw_Comm_Talk_Log.COMM_DATETIME},12,8));
```

Populate the correct date without the string error.

Comment: Hi, there, @Awn85. May you elaborate more about it? What do you mean by "fields are broken"? Do you see any error message? My first shot would be the date time format in server regional options, but if you give more details, maybe i can be more assertive.

Comment: @heringer I have a formula field called date. When I try to validate the code I get an error stating that a string is required here.

Comment: the functions left and mid requires a string. Is COMM_DATETIME of type "date"?

Comment: @heringer COMM_DATETIME is a DateTime type in the database. I believe they are trying to just pull the date out? I have added images of the error and the database field.

Comment: It looks like you don't need the formula at all. Comment the lines in the formula and just return {uvw_Comm_Talk_Log.COMM_DATETIME} and see what happens.